# Timespan Parse error - Input string is not correct format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a timespan from string to TimeSpan type in C# and facing error input string is not in correct format. Kindly help.

```
var LoadDuration = "00:00:03:23422";

TimeSpan.ParseExact(LoadDuration, "hh:mm:ss.ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There is no period in your input.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the `:` between `'`. Also, there is a `f` missing and your miliseconds separator is `:` not a `.`

```
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(LoadDuration, "hh':'mm':'ss':'fffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just copypasted your code, but you have a '.' instead of ':'. This answer could be a comment but I dont have enought reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Its a silly mistake

```
var LoadDuration = "00:00:03:2342";
var f = @"hh\:mm\:ss\:ffff";
var a= TimeSpan.ParseExact(LoadDuration, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```