# TimeSpan Parse issue for varying digits in Milliseconds

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a Timespan where some times the value is  "00:00:03:234222" and sometimes the value is  "00:00:03:234". The below code doesnt work please help. I dont want to maintain multiple formats to parse this.

Kindly help, thanks.

```
var LoadDuration = "00:00:03:234222";
var f = @"hh\:mm\:ss\:ffff";
var a= TimeSpan.ParseExact(LoadDuration, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: For reference, this is a follow up to a [recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189606/timespan-parse-error-input-string-is-not-correct-format) which was a typo.

Comment: @gunr2171 it wasn't only typo, in that question, besides the typo, the `:` was unescaped

Comment: FYI - It's super weird to have a colon separating seconds and fractional seconds.  A decimal point is much more common and makes sense (think: 3.234222 seconds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`F` upper case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#the-fffffff-custom-format-specifier-1) (max 7):

```
var LoadDuration = "00:00:03:234222";
var f = @"hh\:mm\:ss\:FFFFFFF";
var a= TimeSpan.ParseExact(LoadDuration, f, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That way, any number of digits from 0 to 7 will be parsed